# Redirecting user from App part to a List in Host Web

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, provider-hosted-app

In our provider hosted app we have a app part and app part shows a page which has a button. On clicking this button we want to redirect user to a list in Host web.

Is there a way to do this or it's a limitation within SharePoint.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On button click you can add below line for redirecting from App Part to host web. Hope it will help others.

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "redirect", "if(top!=self) {top.location.href = '" + Request["SPHostUrl"] + "';}", true);
```